# How to expand/collapse all rows in Angular

Tags: angularjs, toggle, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngtable

I have successfully created a function to toggle the individual rows of my `ng-table` to open and close using:

```
TestCase.prototype.toggle = function() {
  this.showMe = !this.showMe;
}
```

and

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in $data">

  <td align="left">
    <p ng-click="row.toggle();">{{row.description}}</p>

    <div ng-show="row.showMe">
```

See the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/AHoXoq?p=preview) for more code, note the expand/collapse buttons are in the "menu".

However, I can't figure out a way to now toggle ALL of the rows on and off. I want to be able to somehow run a for loop over the rows and then call toggle if needed, however my attempts at doing so have failed. See them below:

```
TestCase.prototype.expandAllAttemptOne = function() {
   for (var row in this) {
     if (!row.showMe)
     row.showMe = !row.showMe;
   }
}

function expandAllAttemptOneTwo(data) {
   for (var i in data) {
     if (!data[i].showMe) 
     data[i].showMe = !data[i].showMe;
   }
 }
```

Any ideas on how to properly toggle all rows on/off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `ng-show` directive in combination with the `ng-click` and `ng-init` directives, we can do something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="TableController">
  <button ng-click="setVisible(true)">Show All</button>
  <button ng-click="setVisible(false)">Hide All</button>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in persons" 
        ng-click="person.visible = !person.visible" 
        ng-show="person.visible">
    {{person.name}} 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Our controller might then look like this:

```
myApp.controller('TableController', function ($scope) {

  $scope.persons = [
    { name: "John", visible : true}, 
    { name: "Jill", visible : true}, 
    { name: "Sue", visible : true}, 
    { name: "Jackson", visible : true}
    ];

  $scope.setVisible = function (visible) {
    angular.forEach($scope.persons, function (person) {
      person.visible = visible;
    });
  }
});
```

We are doing a couple things here. First, our controller contains an array of `person` objects. Each one of these objects has a property named `visible`. We'll use this to toggle items on and off. Second, we define a function in our controller named `setVisible`. This takes a boolean value as an argument, and will iterate over the entire `persons` array and set each `person` object's `visible` property to that value.

Now, in our html, we are using three angular directives; `ng-click`, `ng-repeat`, and `ng-show`. It seems like you already kinda know how these work, so I'll just explain what I'm doing with them instead. In our html we use `ng-click` to set up our click event handler for our "Show All" and "Hide All" buttons. Clicking either of these will cause `setVisible` to be called with a value of either true or false. This will take care of toggling all of our list items either all on, or all off.

Next, in our `ng-repeat` directive, we provide an expression for angular to evaluate when a list item is clicked. In this case, we tell angular to toggle `person.visible` to the opposite value that it is currently. This effectively will hide a list item. And finally, we have our `ng-show` directive, which is simply used in conjunction with our `visible` property to determine whether or not to render a particular list item.

Here is a plnkr with a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/MlxyvfDo0jZVTkK0gman?p=preview

This code is a general example of something you might do, you should be able to expand upon it to fit your particular need. Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense

Comment: How about if your buttons are inside you `ng-repeat`?